# Refresh selectInput on shiny DropDownList retrieved from RODBC

Tags: r, shiny, rodbc, shiny-reactivity

I have a reactive input in ShinyUI Tab1:

```
selectInput("SelectVar", choices = DropDownListForVar())
```

,where

```
DropDownListForVar()) = function (){
    sqlQuery = return ( Connection, "Select var from dbo.Variables")
} ## using RODBC library
```

In my shiny app, I am also updating the dbo.Variables table from a Tab2. The problem is that I cannot see the updated value in dbo.Variables from Tab1, unless I restart the app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to debug without a reproducible example. My guess is that you lack the [reactive context](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html) for `selectInput` or data retrieval. Please make sure to update the dropdown using `updateSelectInput` and fetch the data with a reactive expression, both inside server. Additionally, to achieve this goal, you need to inform your Shiny App automatically when the database is updated, which could be hard to implement. I would suggest triggering queries with an action button or timer ([`reactiveTimer`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.0/reactiveTimer.html))

Answer (score 0):

I used `updateSelectInput` in server.R:

```
updateSelectInput(session ,"SelectVar", choices = DropDownListForVar())
```

triggered after updating "SelectVar" and it worked fine.

In my case, understanding when the database is updated was easy, since there is only one user at a time adding records on button click. Thank you!